# Create Entity of specific columns

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am using Breeze (http://www.breezejs.com/) and to use the functionality I want it requires mapping to a complete entity and all of its fields. I have a "Person" entity, but it includes a Social Security Number field. I want to keep this SSN# field private so I would like to create an entity named SubSetPerson that is updateable, has navigation properties and only contains the columns I want (e.g. ID, FirstName, LastName, myNavigationProperty) and does not contain the SSN#. I am using database/model first. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using database first, then you could create a view for that table which only selects the columns you want.  Then update the EF model browser to  include that view.

Comment: Creating a view would flatten my data. It may work well for this specific example, but there will be other cases where I'd prefer something else. Are there any other ways besides a view to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flatten my data"?  I would need to understand the case where a view wouldn't be sufficient and why to answer your question properly

Comment: Thanks Justin, I will explore some more with views. I played around a little and am having issues with the Entity Framework mapping Update and Insert commands automatically as well as it not being able to automap my foreign keys, but this may be my best bet right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Master-Detail type structure for your person. The master table would contain the person's public information; ie name, birthdate, etc... The detail table would contain only the more sensitive information (SSN, etc...).  Then depending on your needs you can load the detail or not.